# Function doesn't move image but returns info correctly

Tags: php

I'm tryin to upload 2 images but it seems all to be well but it move_uploaded_file() doesn't move the file, no errors have been generated.

```
// Upload Image
function upload_image($tmp,$name) {
    $ext = explode('.',$name);
    if (preg_match('~(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$~i', $name)) {
    $ext = end($ext);

    $name = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 10).'.' . $ext;
    $upload_dir = '/music/uploads/' . $name;
    echo $tmp;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp,'/home/shadne/public_html'.$upload_dir);

        return $upload_dir;
    } else {
        throw new ErrorException('File type not allowed');
    }
}
```

file/folder permission is 0777, i used images/new before using /uploads

EDIT 1

code that handles the uploading and checkin

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
require 'includes/functions.php';

if (!empty($_FILES['artist_profile_image'])) {
    $profile_image_name = $_FILES['artist_profile_image']['name'];
    $profile_image_tmp = $_FILES['artist_profile_image']['tmp'];
    $profile_image_dir = upload_image($profile_image_tmp, $profile_image_name);
}

if (!empty($_FILES['artist_thumb'])) {
    $thumb_name = $_FILES['artist_thumb']['name'];
    $thumb_tmp = $_FILES['artist_thumb']['tmp'];
    $thumb_dir = upload_image($thumb_tmp, $thumb_name);
}

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('artist_name', 'artist_thumb', 'artist_profile_image', 'birthday');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterstrik are required';
                break 1;
            }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'You\'ve added a new artist.';
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $artist_data = array(
            'artist_name'           => $_POST['artist_name'],
            'artist_thumb'          => $thumb_dir,
            'artist_profile_image'  =>  $profile_image_dir,
            'birthday'              => $_POST['birthday'],
        );

        add_artist($artist_data);
        //exit(header('Location: add_artist.php?success'));

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Admin Area</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<h1>Add Artist</h1>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Artist Name*: <input type="text" name="artist_name" />
        </li>
        <li>
            Artist Thumbnail*: <input type="file" name="artist_thumb" />
        </li>
        <li>
            Artist Profile Image*: <input type="file" name="artist_profile_image" />
        </li>
        <li>
            Birthday*:
                    <input type="date" name="birthday" />
        </li>                    
        <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Artist" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<?php  } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `echo $tmp;` outputting anything? Is that part of the code being reached?

Comment: Can you enable error reporting .. there is so many errors with your script example `substr(md5(rand()), 0, 10).'.' . $ext;` when `$ext` is `array` ...

Comment: @pseudoh not it's not

Comment: This is part of the problem. The tmp should be a valid temporary file as returned by $_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']

Comment: @pseudoh look at the code, added the rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if move_uploaded_file returns true or false. It can silently fail if the input file is not a valid upload file.
What are you sending in to $tmp?

Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php for return values.

Comment: it return false, but i don't know why

Comment: According to the PHP documentation, the temp file is not ["tmp"] but ["tmp_name"], try replacing that in your code, and verify that you actually are getting a filepath from it.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php